# Where is the line buffering occuring? On which stream?

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am transferring bytes between my smartphone and my Raspberry Pi over bluetooth. Pi runs raspbian and has a bluetooth-serial thing attached to its GPIO header. On the smartphone I use various android blueooth console apps.

To view data from the phone in the Pi, at the terminal I am using:

socat /dev/ttyAMA0 -

This works fine, characters are flowing in both directions, everything is working.

But - when I send a string from the phone app to the Pi over bluetooth, only after a newline do I see the string on the Pi terminal. The same is reciprocated from Pi->phone. So line buffering is going on.

Using an oscilloscope I can see that EVERY character I sent from the bluetooth app is resulting in RS232 data, so there is no buffering on the way out of the phone. The buffering is in the Pi somewhere and newline is flushing it.

Can anyone describe where this is? (I am familiar with none/line/block buffering schemes - just not *where* (I think))

Ta
Rich

--- MORE DETAILS ---

So to remove issues with the local terminal on my Raspberry Pi, I wrote the smallest java app to sit in a tight loop reading characters from `/dev/ttyAMA0` using a `FileInputStream`. Literally waits for a byte, prints it to the console (using `println()`) then waits at `read()` again.

I get no characters read until a 0x0A is sent over the bluetooth, at which point all previously buffered characters are output.

This takes `socat` out of the loop and the need for turning off line-buffering there.

There appears to be line-buffering in action still - but where is it?

Rich

Comment: Did your read my answer? Did it helped or I was wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry chap I've not got round to trying yet. Soon!

Comment: Fine, don't worry ;). I was just curious as I cannot try it myself.

Comment: Hi terence - I've stopped using socat as it was introducing another step. Please see my revised question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I've finally solved my issue to enough depth that I can continue with my original path of development.

The cure for me was to issue this TTY setup:
`stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 raw`

where `raw` is an amalgamation of other options - see http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty

The combined options are many but the obvious one appears to be the `min 1`.

So now when I send character from my phone over bluetooth using a bluetooth console, I get the characters appear in real time in my Java program running on my Raspberry Pi.

My java program that reads from the uart-connected bluetooth thing is using the `jSSC` library. That alone did not help with the line buffering. I have to run the `stty ... raw` before running my own app.

A sample from my Java program:

`readBytes() read 1
char 'h value 104
End of readBytes()
readBytes() read 1
char 'e value 101
End of readBytes()
readBytes() read 3
char 'l value 108
char 'l value 108
char 'o value 111
End of readBytes()
readBytes() read 1
char '
 value 10
End of readBytes()`

One will see the LF at the end. All the other "hello" was received as it was sent, rather than received in one readBytes() along with the LF.

Hope this helps someone! I can't see why this is not a more common issue for Pi developers!

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of **socat**:

> " ... when data is available on one side and can be written to the
>   other side, socat reads it, performs newline character conversions if
>   required, and writes the data to the write **file descriptor** of the
>   other stream, then continues waiting for more data in both
>   directions."

I guess that **socat** writes to **stdout** which is line buffered, so you will see the line on your terminal only after the newline.

I never used socat, however, it seems that there are several options to see/set file descriptors, like `CW-D` and  `CWFD:<fdnum>`, refer to the man [page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/socat). I would try to change it to stderr and see what happens.